# Visual studio 2010 Editor input language has changed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor

I have got a problem in Microsoft Visual studio 2010 , When I type some code in source code editor then editor show Hindi . Actually I things i have press some wrong key due to this my Editor's input language has been changed . I have troubled to solve this problem But i have not got solution how i can change my Editor input language as default(English).
  Please Help me...

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Launch Visual Studio.
2. Navigate to Tools>Options>Environment\International Settings
3. Change the Language setting.
4. Relaunch Visual Studio.