# Visual Studio 2010 editor unexpected autocorrection

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, editor

I installed VS2010 32b spanish, and found a strange issue while editing code. When I write "s (in #include "st..." for example), this is automatically converted to a S with an accent mark. Similar issue happens when i write AA, II or UU, but in these cases AA is converted a+hypen (same behaviour for other vowels less O and E). If I write ""s all is ok, but if delete one ", then the remaining "S is again transformed in S with the accent.

I noticed this looks more like a visual effect, because if you copy the "wrong" code and paste it in another editor, it looks perfect: "S is just "S.
Furthermore, VS compiles the code perfectly with these issue, so all points it's some visual..

If I write

```
#include "stdafx.h"

aa ii oo uu
```

VS shows:

```
#include ´Stdafx.h"   <=== 'S is S with accent, but i can't write that here!

â î oo û  <===== aa ii and uu are converted in that while editing.
```

I'm unable to find what is happening or why, and how to remove this annoying effect. I tried different settings that could be related with this (or look so), but nothing worked, so I reverted changes.

Notice OS language and VS is spanish, but I also tried VS in english and the result is the same. I never had this issue before with older versions of VS.

Someone gave me an idea about using a language pack for MsOffice, but really I don't understand why Office could affect VS in such a way or why it didn't with previous versions.

Any idea about what is happening?

[here you can download a small video recorded in VS with the problem](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/6dc87fc0)
(uncheck the download manager suggested, as usual for these file hosting sites, and click the gray button -sorry but i dont have better filehost-)

**Edit:**
I have tried the following solution [Visual studio 2010 Editor input language has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756384/visual-studio-2010-editor-input-language-has-changed?rq=1) because it's similar, but **problem** still **persists**.

Comment: Did you enable any accessibility features? Are file encodings somehow mangled? Any third party add-ins?

Answer (score 1):

I just went into my 2013 VS version and up in the search box typed in language and then selected Environment and in the drop down list I had the option English ( yours probably says Spanish ), however the second one says same as Microsoft Windows.  If you did not try that, give that a shot and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple languages selected in Control Panel > Region and Language > Keyboards and Languages?  If so, you could have accidentally switched language by pressing ALT + LEFT SHIFT.  Switch back by pressing again.